# netperf command doesn't exist on raspbian

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-stretch

I am trying to run some tests about network on my Raspberry Pi 3 B+, and I have raspbian on it. I installed flent via `apt install flent`, and I ensured that non-free repository is enabled.  I still can't run the `netperf` command. Does anybody know how to get the `netperf` command or how to create netserver on Raspberry Pi?

Comment: What distro version are you using? Stretch? Buster? It doesn't seem to show in Buster here: https://packages.debian.org/sid/netperf (I don't know why) I also can't see it in Stretch here http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/dists/stretch/non-free/binary-armhf/Packages

Comment: Would `iperf` be a suitable replacement? https://packages.debian.org/stretch/iperf see https://tooling.bennuttall.com/command-line-speedtest-tools/ for usage

Comment: Ah, it's currently failing to build in Buster: https://tracker.debian.org/news/718492/netperf-removed-from-testing/ So if you're using Buster, that's why.

Comment: I am using Stretch. For tests I need to do iperf is not suitable replacement

Comment: I'll let the Raspbian maintainer know

Comment: @ben_nuttall There seems to be an appropriate answer here if someone has a minute to write it up ;)  The email you linked is dated 2015, so it was likely removed before there ever was a stretch or buster; I do see it in 'non-free' here though: https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=netperf  Importing a .deb for the appropriate platform is worth a try.

Comment: Just waiting on response from the Raspbian maintainer. There's a chance it'll be fixed soon.

Comment: Just posted an answer - unfortunately it's not available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have noticed packages for netperf and flent are missing from Raspbian package repositories. But good news is that it is really easy to get netperf and flent running on Raspberry Pi by manually compiling netperf and installing flent via pip Python package manager.

So just follow these steps:

```
sudo apt install autotools-dev automake
git clone https://github.com/HewlettPackard/netperf.git
cd netperf
./autogen.sh
./configure --enable-demo
make
sudo make install
sudo pip install flent
sudo pip install matplotlib
```

I have tested these steps on fresh new Raspbian image.

Comment: Only strange thing is that flent is not seeing matplotlib, any ideas why?

     ERROR: Unable to plot -- matplotlib is missing! Please install it if you want plots.

Comment: For me, `make` failed with `makeinfo: command not found`. Adding `texinfo` at the end of the line with `apt install` fixed it.

Comment: I also had to install `texinfo` via apt before this worked. Otherwise everything worked great following these instructions!

Answer (score 2):

The Raspbian project does not build nonfree packages. Some nonfree packages are available, but they're just the cross-platform ones imported from upstream Debian.

If you need to install it you'll have to build it from source.

Comment: netperf isn't open source?

Comment: Yes, it's "open source" in as much as the source is available. It's just in "nonfree" because it doesn't comply with Debian's strict licensing terms
https://github.com/HewlettPackard/netperf
https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-archive#s-non-free