# Can't Install netperf on Bullseye

Tags: raspbian, pi-4

I am trying to install netperf on a RPi 4 with Raspbian 11 Bullseye I followed the directions from a previous post, [netperf command doesn't exist on raspbian](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/99695/netperf-command-doesnt-exist-on-raspbian), but receive an error after make
I should note that the src directory does exist and the permissions are correct (755). Also, this did not work when I tried downloading the netperf ZIP file, extracting it, and installing from GitHub too. What should I try next? Here are the details from make:f

```
$ make

make all-recursive

make[1]: Entering directory '/home/user/netperf' Making all in src

make[2]: Entering directory '/home/user/netperf/src' Making all in missing

make[3]: Entering directory '/home/user/netperf/src/missing' Making all in m4

make[4]: Entering directory '/home/user/netperf/src/missing/m4'

make[4]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.

make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/user/netperf/src/missing/m4'

make[4]: Entering directory '/home/user/netperf/src/missing'

make[4]: Nothing to be done for 'all-am'.

make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/user/netperf/src/missing'

make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/user/netperf/src/missing'

make[3]: Entering directory '/home/user/netperf/src'

gcc -o netperf netperf.o netlib.o netsh.o nettest_bsd.o nettest_dlpi.o nettest_unix.o nettest_xti.o nettest_sctp.o nettest_sdp.o nettest_omni.o net_uuid.o dscp.o netcpu_procstat.o -lrt -lm

/usr/bin/ld: nettest_omni.o:(.bss+0x1d0): multiple definition of `loc_nodelay'; nettest_bsd.o:(.bss+0x20): first defined here

/usr/bin/ld: nettest_omni.o:(.bss+0x1d4): multiple definition of `rem_nodelay'; nettest_bsd.o:(.bss+0x24): first defined here

/usr/bin/ld: nettest_omni.o:(.bss+0x1d8): multiple definition of `loc_sndavoid'; nettest_bsd.o:(.bss+0x40): first defined here

/usr/bin/ld: nettest_omni.o:(.bss+0x1dc): multiple definition of `loc_rcvavoid'; nettest_bsd.o:(.bss+0x44): first defined here

/usr/bin/ld: nettest_omni.o:(.bss+0x1e0): multiple definition of `rem_sndavoid'; nettest_bsd.o:(.bss+0x48): first defined here

/usr/bin/ld: nettest_omni.o:(.bss+0x1e4): multiple definition of `rem_rcvavoid'; nettest_bsd.o:(.bss+0x4c): first defined here

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status make[3]: *** [Makefile:420: netperf] Error 1 make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/user/netperf/src'

make[2]: *** [Makefile:474: all-recursive] Error 1 make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/user/netperf/src'

make[1]: *** [Makefile:398: all-recursive] Error 1 make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/netperf'

make: *** [Makefile:337: all] Error 2
```

Comment: netperf seems to have had a lot of changes since 2019 - maybe that's the issue

Comment: though ... `sudo apt install netperf` seems to work - installs the latest 2.7.0 version - is there any reason you want to build it from source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I followed the directions from a previous post, netperf command doesn't exist on raspbian ... When I run sudo apt install netperf I receive the following error. Package netperf is not available, but is referred to by another package.

That Q&A is four years old so cannot possibly refer to bullseye as it was released in 2021. **Are you sure you are using bullseye?**

```
> grep VERSION /etc/os-release 
3:VERSION_ID="11"
4:VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
5:VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye

> apt search netperf
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
flent/oldstable,oldstable 2.0.0-3 all
  FLExible Network Tester for bufferbloat testing and more

flowgrind/oldstable 0.8.2-2 arm64
  Distributed network performance measurement tool

netperf/oldstable 2.7.0-0.1 arm64
  Network performance benchmark

> sudo apt install netperf
The following NEW packages will be installed:
netperf

[...install proceeds normally...]

> which netperf
/usr/bin/netperf
```

It seems to run fine as well. I'd say this might be a difference between the 32 and 64 bit OS releases, but a Debian package search for netperf in bullseye shows it available for all platforms, so there is no reason for it not to be available in RpiOS.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it was 32-bit bullseye.
However, I reinstalled Raspberry Pi OS (Bullseye) 64-bit and had no issues using 
sudo apt install netperf.
So I guess this had something to do with the 32-bit version. The package in the case of apt and maybe the g++ compiler, or source, in the case of building from GitHub or the ZIP file. Thank you all very much for your help! I appreciate it.